# .live() or document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Which one is better for performance when attaching events (click, mouseover, mouseout, etc...)?  I am attaching a lot of event listeners to my elements in liu of :hover events and am wondering if there is a performance difference between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking of it in the wrong way. [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is a very expensive observer, avoid it if you can and use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead. If you are not using ajax or javascript to create DOM nodes after [DOMready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), then you don't have to worry about attaching an observer to the event:

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_node').click(function(){}); // will work fine for all nodes loaded before domready
});
```

Comment: +1, It's worth noting that you can be just as awful with `delegate`.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your needs, But here's a general rule:

**Try to bind with `.bind()` whenever it's possible, Bind with `.live()` as less as you can**

(Note that `bind('event', ...)` has aliases, like '.click()')

So, prefer binding in `document.ready()` than using `.live()` because live consumes much more resources, as is always 'listening' for changes.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Put all your events here, where they'll be live anyway
});
```